# Visual Studio deployment package - stop deleting all files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

Perhaps I'm missing a setting here...seems like I am, but I cant see it!!

I have a deployment package, which works except...it deletes everything in the site that I am deploying to.
I have a web application beneath the site that I am deploying and I dont want that to be touched.
That has its own deployment package.

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: Are you using TFS?  If so look at your TFSBuild.proj file.  It determines the deployment path and deployment actions.